# Why does thinkscript throw these issues when I try to create a counter?

Tags: thinkscript

When I try to create a counter and increment it in an if-else statement the thinkscript compiler throws confusing errors which tell me it's not allowed, yet I've seen this done in several examples.  They even have a reserved word: `rec` in order to allow for incrementing counters.

`score = score + 1;` produces: # Already assigned: Score at...

`rec score = score + 1;` produces:         # identifier already used: score at ...
        # not allowed inside an IF/THEN/ELSE statement

```
#
# TD Ameritrade IP Company, Inc. (c) 2017-2019
#

input price = close;
input length = 9;
input displace = 0;

def score = 0;


def smavrgg = Average(price[-displace], length);
def expMvAvrg = ExpAverage(price[-displace], length);

plot SMA = smavrgg;
SMA.SetDefaultColor(GetColor(1));

plot AvgExp = expMvAvrg;
AvgExp.SetDefaultColor(GetColor(1));


# 1 if uptrend, 0 if downtrend
def lastTrendisUp = (close[0] - close[1]) > 0 ;
def secondLastTrendisUP = (close[1] - close[2]) > 0;
def thirdLastTrendisUP = (close[2] - close[3]) > 0;
def fourthLastTrendisUP = (close[3] - close[4]) > 0;


input lookback = 5;

# defines intBool (array) that indicates whether one or the other crossed. 

def bull_cross = SMA crosses above AvgExp;
def bear_cross = AvgExp crosses below SMA;

# returns the highest value in the data array for the lookback.  
# so [0, 1, 0, 0] means a cross happened within the last units. and 1 will be returned.  



if (bull_cross[0] or bear_cross[0]) then {
    if lastTrendisUp {
        # Already assigned: Score at...
          score = score + 1;


        # identifier already used: score at ...
        # not allowed inside an IF/THEN/ELSE statement
          rec score = score + 1;

    } else {

    }
} else if (bull_cross[1] or bear_cross[1])  {
    if secondLastTrendisUP {

    } else {

    }
} else if (bull_cross[2] or bear_cross[2]) {
    if thirdLastTrendisUP {

    } else {

    }
} else if (bull_cross[3] or bear_cross[3])  {
    if fourthLastTrendisUP {

    } else {

    }
} else if (bull_cross[4] or bear_cross[4])  {

} else {

}

# If most recent cross happened in the last 4
# and most recent cross occured on a green candle.

def bull_lookback = Highest(bull_cross, lookback);
def bear_lookback = Highest(bear_cross, lookback);






# def think = if bull_lookback or bear_lookback  

plot signal = if bull_lookback then 2 else if bear_lookback then 1 else 0;
signal.AssignValueColor(if signal == 2 then Color.DARK_GREEN else if signal == 1 then Color.DARK_RED else Color.DARK_ORANGE);
AssignBackgroundColor(if signal == 2 then Color.DARK_GREEN else if signal == 1 then Color.DARK_RED else Color.DARK_ORANGE);
```

Comment: If you downvote at least have the common courtesy to explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that  variables in thinkscript cannot be changed.

Comment: maybe we should stop calling them "variables" then? XD

Answer (score 1):

Once you define a variable in Thinkscript and assign it, it's only valid for one bar, it behaves as a constant so it can't be reassigned.  I'm pretty sure you can't even place a Def command into a conditional, just like in most codes.  In order to create a 'dynamic' SCORE, you need to assign the dynamic value in the same line you instantiate. You don't need

```
def score = 0;
```

since when you define the variable, it will have a zero value anyway.

You also don't the extra variables for the 'trendisup' placeholders, because really

```
secondLastTrendisUp
```

is the same as saying

```
lastTrendisUp[1]
```

because it was already computed in the last bar.

You can accomplish the counter without the extra variables using a FOLD statement, like this:

```
def score= fold index=0 to 4 
with p=0 
do p + ((bearcross[index] or bullcross[index]) and lastTrendisUp[index]);
```

This will add one to the score each time the conditions are true, and assign the total to the SCORE variable.  I think this is what you would like to accomplish, I can't tell, since you never show what you're doing with the score variable later on...  If you are looking to just find out if **bullcross or bearcross** condition and also the **lasttrendisup** condition evaluates to true in any of the last five bars, then you add 'while p=0' above the with, and it will return a one to SCORE as soon as it encounters the first true instance.

Answer (score 1):

counter to increase a variable by 1, on each bar:

```
score = score[1] + 1;
```

the [1] means, go get the value from that variable from 1 bar ago.